# Count number of times a column has changed value based on current and previous rows

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have the following result set.

```
Product  Date       Status    
123      1/1/2017   Active    
123      2/1/2017   Inactive  
123      3/1/2017   Active    
456      1/1/2017   Active    
456      1/2/2017   Active    
456      1/3/2017   Inactive  
789      1/7/2017   Active    
789      1/15/2017  Active    
789      1/21/2017  Active    
111      1/7/2017   Inactive 
111      1/15/2017  Active    
111      1/21/2017  Inactive  
111      1/23/2017  Active 
111      1/31/2017  Inactive
```

I would like to try to determine the number of times a product changes status, but have each row show that number as of the date of the row.  Alternatively, I could also simply show the distinct count of statuses for each product (also at that given date).

I imagine this will need some sort of window function with a partition on product and ordered by date, but I haven't had luck with any yet.

The desired results would look like this:

```
Product  Date       Status    # of Distinct Status  # of Status Change
123      1/1/2017   Active    1                     0
123      2/1/2017   Inactive  2                     1
123      3/1/2017   Active    2                     2 
456      1/1/2017   Active    1                     0
456      1/2/2017   Active    1                     0
456      1/3/2017   Inactive  2                     1
789      1/7/2017   Active    1                     0
789      1/15/2017  Active    1                     0
789      1/21/2017  Active    1                     0
111      1/7/2017   Inactive  1                     0
111      1/15/2017  Active    2                     1
111      1/21/2017  Inactive  2                     2
111      1/23/2017  Active    2                     3
111      1/31/2017  Inactive  2                     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `lag` and `sum` window functions

```
select id,date,status,
sum(case when prev_status is null or prev_status=status then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by product order by date) as num_of_status_change
from (select id,date,status,lag(status) over(partition by product order by date) as prev_status
      from tbl
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works exactly as expected, hadn't thought of using a case statement in my window function.